# Passing through GET method some hidden values

Tags: php, html, get

I am trying to get the names from a query and passing each one of them through GET Method, so when clicking on an "answer" rank, it will open a child window in which i can find out which user and which value did he valuated the answer.

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo "<div class='answer'>"
        .$row['User']." has answered:
        <dl>                                    
            <dd>".$row['Answer']."</dd>"; ?>            
            <dd> 
                <form method='GET' action='votes.php' >
                    <input type="hidden" name="x" value="<?php echo $row['Answer'];?>"/>
                    <input type='submit'/>
                </form>

                    <a onclick="javascript:popUp()" > 
                        Rank: <?php echo $row['k'];?> 
                    </a>
```

The problem is when i try to get the answers for querying in the votes.php, it says that `$_GET['x']` is undefined?

```html
if(isset($_SESSION['email'])){
    if(isset($_GET['x'])){
        $ans = $_GET['x'];
        $query = "SELECT User, AES_DECRYPT(Vote,'usa') as l
                  FROM voting
                  WHERE Answer = '$ans'";
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Check line number. I can not see `$_POST` variable in your code.

Comment: You won't be able to access form data with `$_POST` unless you specify `method="POST"` in your `<form>` tag.

Comment: i mean $_GET['x'], Sorry for mistaking.

Comment: Again, which line number? Because, there shouldn't be any error on this line: `$ans = $_GET['x']`. It could be possible that you are using that variable outside of if condition.

Comment: $ans = $_GET['x']; Yeah exastly that line. Says undefined x.

Maybe should include x even in the second php file?

Comment: The `if(isset($_GET['x']))` should prevent that error. Check for typos.

Comment: What is the EXACT error message?

Comment: ( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: x in C:\xampp\htdocs\xampp\RankingQuestions\votes.php on line

Comment: Yeah i mean if(isset($_GET['x'])) removes me from the block, but i wanna know why x is not set?